# Using PHP code in PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, templating

I have the following code in PHP:

```
<?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {insert_audio_player("[audio:|titles=]"} ?>
```

Which renders an audio player to my page in WordPress. I need to call a custom field inside this code. My custom field code is also coded in PHP:

```
<?php print_custom_field('tc_filename'); ?>
```

Something like:

```
<?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {insert_audio_player("[audio:<?php print_custom_field('tc_filename'); ?>|titles=<?php print_custom_field('tc_title'); ?>]"} ?>
```

How can I use or integrate the second block of code with the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {
    insert_audio_player("[audio:".print_custom_field('tc_filename')."|titles=".print_custom_field('tc_title')."]"
} ?>
```

You can make this easier to read using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
<?php 
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {
    insert_audio_player(sprintf(
        '[audio:%s|titles=%s]', 
        print_custom_field('tc_filename'), 
        print_custom_field('tc_title')
    ));
} 
?>
```

**Edit**: based on your comment, the print_custom_field actually echo's the field, and doesn't return it, if there is no return function you can use, you need to use [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

You can use a new function, which calls the print function but returns it instead of printing it to the screen:

```
function get_custom_field($field) {
    ob_start();
    print_custom_field($field);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And use

```
<?php 
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {
    insert_audio_player(sprintf(
        '[audio:%s|titles=%s]', 
        get_custom_field('tc_filename'), 
        get_custom_field('tc_title')
    ));
} 
?>
```

Comment: I believe you're missing a closing `)`.

Comment: @Jacob: I believe I missed one as well. You were originally missing two. :)

Comment: @Jacob @jnpcl @AbiusX Thanks for your answers. Maybe it's a feature of wordpress or audio player plugin, but then I add any of your code i have tc_filename var before [audio:] tag =\ I don't understand why. Something like: `test.mp3[audio:]`

Comment: @alekseygr I've updated the answer to use output buffering, the print functions you use are echo data and not returning it.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your answer, but then I use your code I have `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}` at the end of second part of code.

Comment: @alekseygr, sorry there was a missing semicolon, fixed now.

Comment: @Jacob Sorry, but have this one: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'` =)

Comment: Missing the second closing `)` .. (`sprintf` is closed, but `insert_audio_player` is not)

Comment: Thx, fixed. But now have a wordpress error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_custom_field()`(previously declared in /plugins/custom-content-type-manager/includes/functions.php

Comment: @jnpcl thanks again! I should really do this in an IDE first :D @alkseygr, looks like wordpress already has that function for you, so you don't need to do the output buffering, just use the last code without adding the new function.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: As stated by the OP, the `print_custom_field()` function uses `echo` rather than `return`, so this answer will not work for this particular situation. See @Jacob's answer for a better solution.**

Try this:

```
<?php
    if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {
        insert_audio_player(
            "[audio:" . print_custom_field('tc_filename') .
            "|titles=" . print_custom_field('tc_title') . "]"
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now trying to implement @Jacob's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {insert_audio_player("[audio:".function2()."|titles=".function3()."]"} ?>
```

then :

```
function function2()
{
print_custom_field('tc_filename');
}
function function3()
{
print_custom_field('tc_title');
}
```

Comment: you can add if and other logic that way.

Comment: perhaps you should mention that, and not use names like function2 and function3.

Comment: perhaps, but look at the question.

Comment: @AbiusX can you refer to what part of the question asks for that?

Comment: i meant the question is too basic too simply concat functions to the string! so i defined new functions for the questionee to understand better.